# Chat system with messages at the bottom of the div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a simple chat system, like that facebook does with messenger, keep the new messages at bottom. But they add a header and keep the fix position whit the last message and of course the scrollbar

[Here is my try... but no scrollbar and the header do not move too.](https://jsfiddle.net/zj1mz7sx/)

keep in mind, I do not want a fixed header. The problem for as I did read is that "height:auto" in chat div makes it "flow", but that is what keep the chat height dynamic. 
well ... if anyone has a better solution to keep the messages at bottom, with header at top and when the message reach the header gets sticky, please.

[PS: With only the ccs3 display:flex, I been able to achieve my goal here.. very simple.. It's possible without ? even with JS](https://jsfiddle.net/cLtkt0sw/)'    '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo, check this out

```js
(function(i) {
  $(".click").click(function() {

    if (parseInt($(".chat .placeholder").css("margin-bottom")) > 32) {
      $(".chat .placeholder").css("margin-bottom", "-=50px");
    }

    else if ($(".chat .placeholder").css("margin-bottom") == "32px") {
      $(".chat .placeholder").css("margin-bottom", "0px");
    }

    $(".chat").append("<p>hey " + (++i) + "</p>");
   
   $(".chat").scrollTop( $(".chat").prop('scrollHeight') - $(".chat").outerHeight() );

  })
})(0);
```

```css
.main .chat {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  background: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.chat p {
  background: blue;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.main .header {
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  height: 18px;
}

p.placeholder {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 132px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' class='click' value='add'>
<div class='main'>

  <div class='chat'>
    <p class="placeholder header">Header</p>
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the z-index only make the "header" visible over the others divs "absolute||relate" and with behavior like a fixed div..  i wanna that chat divs expands and grows header out the screen, creating a scrollbar in main div keeping new messages at the bottom. exactly like facebook does.

Comment: here still the same. header fixed. I be able to made with display:flex.. but i need with only css2..  check the flex version https://jsfiddle.net/cLtkt0sw/. thanks

Comment: @RicardoGomes I changed the header. CHeck it now.

Comment: Nop.. now the header has a "margin" between .chat "the blue". so not sticky..  look at the version i made with display:flex. But i need to work in safari:ios and doesn't.. I am trying with tables.. seems it how facebook does. Thank you ..

Comment: @RicardoGomes I looked your version. Now I have made my demo pixel by pixel same as yours.

Comment: thanks and sorry the delay. Seems to do the trick, i didn't have time to test, but one thing i saw is that you did fixed values. 32px,50px. Because it is a dynamic contets, maybe this will be a problem.. even using outerheigh(true).. i will try tonight with time the code.. anyway.. thank you for the effort and then probably i will give to you the right anwser.

Comment: @RicardoGomes 32px and 50px can be changed to dynamic values like `$(".chat p"),height()`. But at the end since  `p`'s font size and padding are static in css so same static values can be used in js. May be you'd be using sass in that case you can turn all 32 and 50 stuff dynamic as I told in first line.

Answer (score 0):

Now I see what your problem is:

Just remove `position: absolute;` from .chat

Comment: thanks for the answer, Yes.. but this isn't the problem. i wanna the header been outside .. grow as .chat expands not an above the header.

Comment: Redid my answer. Forget the z-index stuff

Comment: then messages will keep at the top and new ones will arrive below the old ones. and the header it's fixed. my goal here is new messages at bottom, history grows to the top and when reaches header make it sticky to the message. and of course the scrollbar. A! and if possible, without javascript!! i just found out the "display:flex" .. if without this new ccs3 stuff.. better. Thank you